# Creating a function, it's getting stuck in a loop for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a very basic function that takes a string and returns the most common characters in a list. For some reason, it's getting stuck in the loop. Here's the code:

```
def frequent(string, amount):
    '''frequent(str) --> list
    This function takes a string and returns a list of the
    most frequent characters in order, without repetition.'''
    values = []
    common = ''
    while len(values) != amount:
        for char in string:
            if string.count(char) > string.count(common):
                common = char
                values.append(char)
                string = string.strip(char)
    return values
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead; it does what you want out of the box: `return Counter(string).most_common()[0][0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code gets stuck in a loop because when `common == ""`, i.e. when the `while` loop starts running, `string.count(common) == len(string) + 1` (*not* `0`, as you expect). Therefore, you never find any more-common `char`s to add to `values`, so `values` never grows long enough to end the loop.

Also, you don't seem to have any plan to remove less common `char`s from `values` when more common ones are found.

As Martijn points out, this is easily achieved with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def frequent(s, n):
    """Returns a list of the n most frequent characters in s."""
    return [char for char, count in Counter(s).most_common(n)]
```

You might also want to consider adding handling for lower and upper case characters (does `'a'` count as `'A'`?), whitespace and punctuation.